# Inverse of a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, inverse-function

Let $A$ be a closed bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous injective function. Then $f^{-1} : f(A) \rightarrow A$ is also continuous.

That $A$ is closed and bounded are both crucial conditions. Therefore I need to give an example of a continuous injective function $f:A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on a closed but unbounded set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$  for which $f^{-1}$ is not continuous. Can anyone give me a hint on this?

(I know the question has already been asked on [A continuous injective function and its inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665457/a-continuous-injective-function-and-its-inverse), but the comment given does not make it clear to me yet.)

Comment: Duplicate? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2259953/432669 (different from the one cited)

Comment: @bloomers Not a duplicate as it doesn't answer the question in the second paragraph.

Comment: Ah.  My mistake.

Answer (score 6):

Let $A = [0,1] \cup [2,\infty).$ Then $A$ is closed. Define

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \,x, & x\in [0,1]\\ 
1+\dfrac{1}{x}, & x\in [2,\infty) \end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is continuous and injective on $A,$ and $f(A)= [0,3/2].$ But $f^{-1}: [0,3/2] \to A$ is discontinuous at $1,$ as $\lim_{x\to 1^-} f^{-1}(x) = 1,$ $\lim_{x\to 1^+} f^{-1}(x) = \infty.$

---

Previous answer: Hint: Think about the map $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb R$ given by $f(1)=0,f(n)=1/n, n=2,3,\dots $

Comment: The usual gestalt of "continuous" is subtle for a function from the integers to the reals (although the topological definition is still unambiguous, it does not match the sort of $\epsilon-\delta$ intuitive meaning). So I would look for a cleaner example.

Comment: @ MarkFischler Cleaner? This is a pretty clean example. I can see why one might ask for a less devious example. But I don't think you'll find one. For $A$ to be an example, it has to be fairly badly disconnected. In fact I'm pretty sure it must have infinitely many connected components.

Comment: N is not bounded.

Comment: @WilliamElliot  Of course it isn't. Did you read the question?

Comment: What a beautiful example!

Comment: @MarkFischler Actually, I was wrong about that. $A$ does have to be disconnected, but it need not have more than two connected components. See my edited answer. Thanks for the prodding.

Comment: @KennyWong Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this new edited example fits the bill in all respects. +1

Comment: @zhw.  If $A=\mathbb R$ then it is possible?